# Setting a cron job for python script

Tags: cron, cron-task, crontrigger

I want to run the following command for cron job

```
python test.py -sau 0 -bg 200000 -t mcs3245 > g2g.log
```

I have setup a cron job like below

```
5 0 * * * /local/mnt/workspace/username/scripts/python test.py -sau 0 -bg 200000 -t mcs3245 > g2g.log
```

am getting the following error

```
/bin/sh: /local/mnt/workspace/username/scripts/python: No such file or directory
```

Can anyonehelp on what is wrong and how to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Unless `/local/mnt/workspace/username/scripts/` is the directory of your python installation I would suggest something like this:

```
5 0 * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/script/test.py -sau 0 -bg 200000 -t mcs3245 > g2g.log
```

If you want to execute the script as user USERNAME:

```
5 0 * * * USERNAME /usr/bin/python /path/to/script/test.py -sau 0 -bg 200000 -t mcs3245 > g2g.log
```

Found that last one [here on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/170866/how-to-run-a-cron-job-as-a-specific-user).